# How to display photos from folders onto web page in PHP

Tags: php, html, dynamic, upload, photo

Picture a upload link used to up load JPEG, PNG, and GIF into a folder called /originals. Then a code standardizes the dimensions of the photos to a thumbnail and saves the new thumbnail in the /thumbnails folder.

How can I now display the thumbnail photo in an array in a 6 columned table in the webpage as soon as its uploaded?

My php block:

```
 <?php

$files = scandir("./."/thumbnails);
$numFiles = count($files);

 if($numFiles < 3)
{
echo "<p>Gallery is empty </p>";
}
else 
{
echo "<p> click thumbnail </p>";
echo "<table><tr>";
for($i = 0; $i < $numfiles -2; $i++)
{
    if($i % $Num_COLUMNS == 0 && $i != 0)
        {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
        }
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href='ViewPicture.php?src=".urlencode($files[i +2])."' target='_blank'><img src='".GALLERY_THUMBNAILS.urlencode($files[$i + 2])."' alt='".$files[$i + 2])."' title='".$files[$i + 2]."'/></a>'";
    echo "</td>";
}
echo "</tr> </table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you attempted this yourself yet? Try first before asking for this level of guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function in PHP to get all files. Then loop through the result and output an `<img>` tag for each file.